# Prestashop Admin Catalog Editing Page becomes Unresponsive after opening

Tags: apache, prestashop-1.6

Getting Page Unresponsive error after opening Prestashop -> Catalog -> Product -> Edit.

Have tried to delete the log files and free up space in Server also but it didn't help much.

Also deleted the cache and minified the JS and CSS from the admin Panel but still chrome is throwing the error.

[image: Prestashop Throwing Error On Catalog Edit Page]

Comment: Do you know if Prestashop is throwing some PHP error? It should be in your `admin<suffix>` folder, file `error_log`. It may be because PHP needs more resources.

Comment: @JavierElices It is not throwing any error too ! I checked the apache error and access logs too. I saw the error logs in Prestashop by visting Admin Panel -> Logs as I was not able to see any error_log file in adminXXXX folder.

Comment: Just in case, try adding a file named `php.ini` under the admin directory. There add the lines `memory_limit = 512M`, `max_input_vars = 20000`, and `max_execution_time = 300`.

Comment: Tried it too, but still facing the issue. Also have edited the php.ini pf /etc/php5/apache2

Comment: Did you check that it is in effect with `php_info()`? I am out of tricks on this one... If the memory is not the problem, maybe the execution time. Other than that...

Comment: Could you please upvote my question, so that it reaches to more people

Comment: I checked php_info(), it pointed out me the /etc/php5/fpm path https://soldcity.be/x.php I changed several parameters like max_execution_time, max_input_time, etc to the higher no, but it didn't work